# Copying columns on a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to copy columns from an input file and put it on to an output file. For example in my input file I want to copy row[2] on to row[15] of an output file. IN the code below whats happening is it is copying row[2] of input and paste it on row[0] of output, which makes sense from the code. How can I make it work for row[18] ?

```
for path in glob.glob("out.csv"):
  if path == "out1.csv": continue
  with open(path) as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    for row in reader:
        if row[8] == 'READ' and row[10] == '1110':
            writer = csv.writer(out1, dug1)
            writer.writerow([row[2]])
            writer.writerow(row
```

Comment: how much data are you working with? How many rows/Columns. Could you provide a sample? The reason I ask is, the easy way out would be to read in both files into memory, add the needed line in the needed position, then rewrite the entire file.

Comment: What happens if you make a list `row` of length `n` (n being 15 or 18 or whatever your use case is) and copy the desired value into the proper index of this list, then call `writer.writerow(row)`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe either you are looking for a fixed rows output or dynamic row output based on what you read from your CSV. You read all the rows in single go from the reader. Change

```
reader = csv.reader(fh)
```

to

```
rows = list(csv.reader(fh))
```

> If you have huge CSV file then above is not recommended as it would load the whole file in memory and you don't want that to happen.

Now you have a `rows` variable which has all the rows from the csv. If you  want to peak into a specific row, col use `rows[row-1][col-1]`.

If you want to write a specific row to your CSV then you can use `rows[row-1]` and write then to csv.

```
writer.writerow(rows[row-1])
```

If you want to mix certain columns from the row then you need to use array slices

```
writer.writerow(rows[row-1][:3] + ["my","data"] + rows[row-1][5:])
```

Above you should have enough examples to achieve what you are looking for